# What is the Flickr API for downloading a picture or URL to the picture

Tags: oauth, flickr

I wanted to download a picture from the Flickr using the flicker API.
I am using OAuth for authentication.

When I searched on the site, I got an API called [flickr.photos.getInfo](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html). But it only gives the path to the page where the picture belongs.

Can anyone tell me where I can get an API to get the actual path to an image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh I got the answer.

The API function is called [flickr.photos.getSizes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html).

Very confusing names.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the urls by requesting them in the extras fields in the appropriate get methods, listed as part of the documentation for each getter method.

For a sample search, use this form http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getRecent with the extras field set to:

> url_sq, url_t, url_s, url_q, url_m, url_n, url_z, url_c, url_l, url_o

PS. I would include the direct links but am currently limited to one link per post.

Comment: What does url_m do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the flickr.photos.getSizes API. When you call the method, you will get the link of that picture ( avaible with different sizes)

Use that link to download.